# Reattaching loose trim

Tags: trim

I have some outside door trim that has come loose. Below are two pictures showing the difference between the top and bottom of the trim.
[image: Bottom of trim that is loose]
[image: Top of trim that is tight]

I looked at this [thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/77350/wood-trim-that-has-come-loose) but it was not very helpful as the selected answer talked about taking the wood, gluing it, and clamping, but there is no part of this trim that would allow it to be easily clamped. If anyone has any suggestions how how to tighten this back together I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible to squirt a little glue in there and then put some finishing nails in it?

Comment: I tried just putting a finishing nail in their and the problem is that wood is very rigid so a nail just passes through both without bringing them together.

Comment: What about using a screw until the glue has time to harden? Is it possible to press the board where it should be with your hand? If it isn't, there could be a broken off nail or something in there preventing it from bending in to place like it should. Also, if you had large enough C clamps you could try that, but that would involve leaving your door open. Alternatively if you can find enough weight, you can lean/scoot something up against the trim to hold it in place while glue sets up.

Comment: I'll try this weekend and get back with my results!